# Wrapping divs inside figure tag?

Tags: html, image, figure

I am wondering is it proper to put wrapping divs for each of several thumbs inside the figure tag (like in the example code below)?

```
<figure>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="castle1423.jpeg" title="Etching. Anonymous, ca. 1423." alt="The castle has one tower, and a tall wall around it."></div>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="castle1858.jpeg" title="Oil-based paint on canvas. Maria Towle, 1858." alt="The castle now has two towers and two walls."></div>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="castle1999.jpeg" title="Film photograph. Peter Jankle, 1999." alt="The castle lies in ruins, the original tower all that remains in one piece."></div>
</figure>
```

Or is there any more appropriate/simpler way to combine both html5 semantics and good styling of thumbs img elements?

Comment: What you've got is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest using nested figure/figcaptions

```
 <figure>
 <figcaption>The castle through the ages: 1423, 1858, and 1999 respectively.</figcaption>
 <figure>
  <figcaption>Etching. Anonymous, ca. 1423.</figcaption>
  <img src="castle1423.jpeg" alt="The castle has one tower, and a tall wall around it.">
 </figure>
 <figure>
  <figcaption>Oil-based paint on canvas. Maria Towle, 1858.</figcaption>
  <img src="castle1858.jpeg" alt="The castle now has two towers and two walls.">
 </figure>
 <figure>
  <figcaption>Film photograph. Peter Jankle, 1999.</figcaption>
  <img src="castle1999.jpeg" alt="The castle lies in ruins, the original tower all that remains in one piece.">
 </figure>
</figure>
```

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element

Comment: In other words: you can treat figure tags as divs in that case, right?